# Whats the best way to swap two ListView items in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

Whats the best way to swap two ListView items in C#? I see that the standard ListView doesn't implement such functionality.

--
Best Regards,
Murat

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the KnowDotNet article ref'd by Murat, here's my extension method that is a bit more flexible (it operates on any item, not just the cursel), and bugfixed (BeginUpdate/Endupdate for less flicker, EnsureVisible, and bounds checking). 
Doesn't need to be an extension method, but I like them :)

```
namespace YourApp
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        // Based upon http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/listviewmoveitem.html
        public static void MoveSelectedItem(this System.Windows.Forms.ListView lv, int idx, bool moveUp)
        {
            // Gotta have >1 item in order to move
            if(lv.Items.Count > 1)  
            {
                int offset = 0;
            if (idx >= 0)
            {
                if (moveUp)
                {
                    // ignore moveup of row(0)
                    offset = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ignore movedown of last item
                    if (idx < (lv.Items.Count - 1))
                        offset = 1;
                }
            }

                if (offset != 0)
                {
                    lv.BeginUpdate();

                    int selitem = idx + offset;
                    for (int i = 0; i < lv.Items[idx].SubItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string cache = lv.Items[selitem].SubItems[i].Text;
                        lv.Items[selitem].SubItems[i].Text = lv.Items[idx].SubItems[i].Text;
                        lv.Items[idx].SubItems[i].Text = cache;
                    }

                    lv.Focus();
                    lv.Items[selitem].Selected = true;
                    lv.EnsureVisible(selitem);

                    lv.EndUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom ListViewItem, or object you cannot clone object, or stock in string:

```
enum Direction { UP = -1, DOWN = +1};

void ListViewMove(ListView lv, Direction direction)
{
    if (lv.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        int selIdx = lv.SelectedItems[0].Index;
        ListViewItem tmp = lv.Items[selIdx] ;

        if ( ( (selIdx != 0) && direction == Direction.UP ) ||
            ((selIdx!=lv.Items.Count-1) && (direction == Direction.DOWN)) )
        {          
            lv.Items.RemoveAt(selIdx);
            tmp = lv.Items.Insert(selIdx + (int)direction, tmp);
            tmp.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    lv.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ASP.NET and Winforms `ListView` have `Items` property which allows to add or removed items.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve wrote a little sample that should work.

```
    ListViewItem[] copyOfItemsInListView1 = new ListViewItem[listView1.Items.Count];
    ListViewItem[] copyOfItemsInListView2 = new ListViewItem[listView2.Items.Count];

    listView1.Items.CopyTo(copyOfItemsInListView1, 0);
    listView2.Items.CopyTo(copyOfItemsInListView2, 0);

    listView1.Items.Clear();
    listView2.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < copyOfItemsInListView2.Length; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(copyOfItemsInListView2[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < copyOfItemsInListView1.Length; i++)
    {
        listView2.Items.Add(copyOfItemsInListView1[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked for: this copies them from one LV ctrl to another

Comment: True. I've read the question again and see that I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Clone them:

```
// move selected item up
int selectedIndex = mListView.SelectedIndices[0];
if (selectedIndex > 0)
{
   ListViewItem item1 = (ListViewItem)mListView.Items[selectedIndex - 1].Clone();
   ListViewItem item2 = (ListViewItem)mListView.Items[selectedIndex].Clone();
   mListView.Items[selectedIndex - 1] = item2;
   mListView.Items[selectedIndex] = item1;

   mListView.SelectedIndices.Remove(selectedIndex);
   mListView.SelectedIndices.Add(selectedIndex - 1);
}
```